# Вопрос по циклу md5 hashlib хеширования

Tags: python

Всем привет! столкнулся с необъяснимой ситуацией: есть цикл, который получает слово рандомом, а потом хеширует его в md5 при помощи hashlib и записывает в тхт-файл. Слова рандомом получает как надо, но почему то хеш в выходном файле получается один и тот же, как будто хешируется одно и то же слово. не пойму почему так:

```
import random
from hashlib import md5
import requests
import time
out = input (r'Укажите файл для сохраниния: ')
out2 = open (out, 'w')
slovar = ('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
for i in range (99):
    randomm = random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar)
    randomm2 = md5(b'randomm').hexdigest()
    r = requests.get ('http://mysite.com/'+ str(randomm2))
    out2.write (randomm2 + '+' + str(r.status_code) + '\n')
    time.sleep (1)
out2.close
```

Comment: просто переменную randomm не получалось оставить, потому что нужно добавлять b

Comment: str не пройдет для хеширования

Comment: [этот коммент был первым] Дайте угадаю, получается `2f8703a73bc2e86bad9a6ddf4631ae43`? Ну так это хэш от слова `randomm`, оно у вас в `md5(b'randomm')` и прописано и вы берёте хэш от него. Может, вы хотели вместо этого `md5(randomm)`?

Comment: еще вопрос: не подскажете как изящнее оформить эту строку: randomm = random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar) + random.choice(slovar) чтобы не писать несколько раз одно и то же (типа *4)

Comment: Например `''.join(random.choice(slovar) for _ in range(4))`

Comment: @dimahimma, если встречается один и тот же кусок повторяющегося кода, его можно в функцию обернуть

Comment: И кстати можно сделать `import string; slovar = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в строчке

```
randomm2 = md5(b'randomm').hexdigest()
```

Выше у вас есть переменная `randomm`, наверное, просто опечатка.

Попробуйте поменять на:

```
randomm2 = md5(randomm.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: да ваш вариант помог, спасибо!

Comment: @dimahimma, тогда примите ответ как правильный (галочка слева от ответа) и поставьте что ответ полезен (стрелочка вверх) ;)

Comment: конечно, 34 секунды и поставлю :)